# Get an image with a width greater than special value

Tags: jquery, css

I try to get an image with a width greater than special value from images list, I use code below, but it doesn't work. What's wrong?  How to make it work?

```
$('.carousel .slideItem img').each(function(){
     var img_width = $(this).css('width');
     console.log(img_width);
     if( img_width > 400 ){
         var img_src = $(this).attr('src');
         console.log(img_src);
     }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`.css('width')` will return the computed width of your element, which will be *x* pixels (e.g 40px). When you attempt to compare this, JavaScript will try to cast this as an integer, resulting in `img_width` being `NaN`.

Use [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to get the width in pixels as an integer:

```
$('.carousel .slideItem img').each(function () {
    var img_width = $(this).width();
    console.log(img_width);
    if (img_width > 400) {
        var img_src = $(this).attr('src');
        console.log(img_src);
    }
})
```

Comment: @Daniel It would, but would be re-inventing the wheel. Also, you should be specifying a radix when using `parseInt()`.